# When someone has no idea about your difficulties and says "do something" or asks you not to do something

Tags: sentence-request

Please imagine someone is dealing with a very difficult challenge in their lives and you as the second person who is watching everything from afar and is outside of the matter just say: you have to do lalala or you shouldn't do ...

There is a proverb in my mother language which says:

> [Direct translation]: He stands on the side of the pit and says: “through him down!”.

Meaning that it is not his / her problem, so he doesn't have any idea how difficult it can be! So, just orders doing... because has no idea about the challenge.

I was wondering if you could let me if there is an equivalent for this proverb in English at all or there isn't.

Comment: You should "walk a mile in my shoes".

Comment: "The admonition to walk a mile in someone else's shoes means before judging someone, you must understand his experiences, challenges, thought processes, etc. The full idiom is: Before you judge a man, walk a mile in his shoes. In effect, it is a reminder to practice empathy." [LINK](http://grammarist.com/phrase/walk-a-mile-in-someone-elses-shoes/) So you could also tell the person they have little or no empathy for the situation.

Comment: @TRomano not at all. They are absolutely different things. I guess there is no any equivalent for it. Could you possibly let me know what would you say  if you were going to tell such a thing "exactly what I said in my original post"?

Comment: @A-friend. Then I have completely misconstrued your words, possibly because I've not understood the antecedent of **he**: "...he (the person who advocates tossing the other person into the pit) doesn't have any idea how difficult it can be" (for that person...he has no idea about the challenges facing that person whom he would have thrown into the pit). Please explain what you meant by them. Are you saying that your proverb identifies with those persons who think that  throwing the person into the pit is *easier said than done*?

Comment: @TRomano yes, I somewhat meant so (easier said than done). Does this idiom work here? Or can you offer something more appropriate?

Comment: **Easier said than done** would work. Why would someone be thrown into a pit? To be stoned to death?